# Get closest textarea attribute id after select list change

Tags: html, jquery

I am new to jquery, am working on small task. I'm trying to find closest textarea attribute id but get undefined.

```
    <div class="input-label-f">
       <div class="select2-wrap">
             <select class="variables_select" name="cars" id="cars">
                  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>

       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-box">
      <textarea id="email_admin_textarea" class="input-field"></textarea>
    </div>


$('.variables_select').change(function(){
    var input = $(this).closest('textarea').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: The closest() method returns the first ancestor of the selected element, thus you'd need to have a textarea as a parent element of your select element for it to work. This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add both `select` and `textarea` in same `div` for reference

```js
$('.variables_select').change(function(){
    var input = $(this).closest('.input-label-f').find('textarea').attr('id');
    console.log(input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-label-f">
       <div class="select2-wrap">
             <select class="variables_select" name="cars" id="cars">
                  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>

       </div>
    

    <div class="input-box">
      <textarea id="email_admin_textarea" class="input-field"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
```